# Cancelling PFQuery quicker due to no network connection

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, network-programming, pfquery

I am trying to cancel a query and set a notice for the user when there is no connection. Is there a better way of doing this than what I've found? The query still runs for about 15+ seconds before the alert happens.

```
    let query = Item.query()

    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects! {
                self.items.append(object as! Item)
                if self.items.count == 35 {
                    break
                }
            }
        } else if error!.code == 100 {
            query?.cancel()
            print("query cancelled")
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops", message: "Trouble With Network", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else  {
            print("non network Error with query")
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check if Parse is reachable before launching the query? The code I always use (in Objective-C, not difficult to convert this to Swift though) is the following, and uses the Reachability framework

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import "Reachability.h"

@property (nonatomic, readonly) int networkStatus;

- (BOOL)isParseReachable {
return self.networkStatus != NotReachable;
}
```

And then just call the method before you start the query. If it returns `NO`, you can display a message to the user and skip the query.